# TodoList React || Ошибка, возможно синтаксис

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list

Два дня ломаю голову, не могу найти ошибку, гуру React помогите.
Вот код -

```
"use strict";

function TitleName(props) {
    return <h1 className="TitleName">TitleName</h1>;
}

class TodoList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tasksArray: [],
            value: ''
        }
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        });  
    }

    onSubmit(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        const newItem = {
            value: this.state.value,
            id: this.state.tasksArray.length
        };
        this.setState(e => ({
            tasksArray: e.tasksArray.concat(newItem),
            value: ''
        }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <TitleName/>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <input placeholder="Введите задачу" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Добавить задачу"/>
                </form>
            <TodoTask tasks={this.state.tasksArray}/>  
            </div>          
        );
    }
}

class TodoTask extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const tasks = this.props.tasks.forEach(currentValue => {
            return (
               <li key={currentValue.id}>
                    {currentValue.value}
                    <button type="submit" id={currentValue.id}>Delete</button>
                </li>   
            );

        });
        return (
            <ul>
                {tasks}
            </ul>  
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <TodoList />,
    document.querySelector("#main")
);
```

Задачи `tasks` не выводятся, `ul` тэг есть, а `li` - нет.

Comment: что за ошибка-то?

Comment: @Grundy ошибки нет, просто задачи не выводятся, ul есть , а li нет

Comment: Вы, наверно, вместо `forEach` хотели `map` написать ?

Comment: Не понимаю в чем разница в данном случаи, и вывод один и тот же)

Comment: например разница в том, что `forEach` ничего не возвращает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в методе рендеринга Вы использовали метод [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> Метод `forEach()` выполняет указанную функцию один раз для каждого
>   элемента в массиве. Возвращаемое значение - `undefined`.

Метод `forEach()` ничего не возвращает, поэтому Вы не видите `<li>...</li>` тэгов. Для того, чтобы их увидеть - необходимо использовать метод [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> Метод `map()` создаёт новый массив с результатом вызова указанной
>   функции для каждого элемента массива. Возвращаемое значение - новый массив, где каждый элемент является результатом `callback` функции.

Таким образом Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так (можно обойтись без переменной `tasks` и мапить результат сразу, но это уже другая история):

```
render() {
  const tasks = this.props.tasks.map(currentValue => {
    return (
      <li key={currentValue.id}>
        {currentValue.value}
        <button type="submit" id={currentValue.id}>Delete</button>
      </li>   
    );
  });

  return (
    <ul>
      {tasks}
    </ul>  
  );
}
```

Comment: Просто нереально вам вам благодарен, спасибо